# delphi ocr: what libabry should I use?

Tags: delphi

Hello
has someone already used a OCR activex/Dll/libary in Delphi ?
I cannot find a library for OCR (Free or for an affordable price)

regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [tesseract-ocr](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) is an open source OCR engine for VC++, but there was [a simple Delphi wrapper for its `tessdll`](http://groups.google.com/group/tesseract-ocr/msg/47c747019c1244ab).
- [Imaging Toolkit for Delphi](http://www.mcm-design.dk/index.php?section=order&product=ImagingDelphi) costs 75 euro for its standard edition.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

http://delphimagic.blogspot.com/2009/04/ocr-con-delphi.html

it takes with source code

Answer (score 0):

at http://OpenOCR.org one can download CuneiForm sources.

they told to go with tiger.tlb file that can be imported into Delphi as COM server ( APARTMENTTHREAD )